# How to turn on indent structure lines in VS2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I accidently turned them off somehow. But I cannot find a hotkey or setting to turn them on again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in Tools + Options, Text Editor, last checkbox.

Comment: Ah thank you. Is it possible to set this for different file types? Now my .cs files have those lines, but .cshtml is still without.

Comment: For VS 2017 RC the Visual Studio Blog [stated this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/11/28/productivity-in-visual-studio-2017-rc/):  
  
  "In Visual Studio 2017 RC, Structure Visualizer works for XAML, C# and VB files, and for all the languages supported via TextMate grammars, as shown in the screenshot below of a Ruby file. You can expect to see more languages add support later. For some languages (like C#, VB), the tooltips are colorized just like the code they reflect too."  

I don't know if that has been changed for VS 2017 RTM.

Comment: What about XML files?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: Just had a look at it - unfortunately no structure lines for XML files.

Comment: Ok. I assume XSL too then? I had been using IndentGuide extension but thought it was not needed anymore.